# XMLReader shows invalid xml, how to get the reason of invalid xml?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I am getting xml data from the url but XMLReader says xml format is invalid.
Can i get any clue about the xml format issue?

I am not expert in XML standard but data seems to be okay with tag wise.

```
$url = "http://xyz";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$folderReader = new XMLReader();  
$folderReader->XML($xml);          //returns true

var_dump($folderReader->isValid());  //bool(false)

print_r($folderReader);  //XMLReader Object ( )
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on php website

"isValid() always returns false unless you enable checking for validity by: 
$reader->setParserProperty(XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);"

Comment: i tried to set it manually but XMLReader content is still empty.